# constraint layout left and right constraint

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a constraint layout and when the string is long enough it overlaps the element on the right. Sample code is:

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconIv"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>



  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/iconIv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/priceFl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
  </FrameLayout>

 ...
```

[image]

Then I tried to nameTv to add right constraint to left of the element on the right like this `app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/priceFl"` and this happened:

[image]

Is there a way to position this text between icon and price views?

Comment: Can you add xml code here

Comment: @MayankPanchal, can you take a look again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/iconIv"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/priceFl"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: fyi if you use this snippet without setting the width to `0dp` it will be centered

Answer (score 2):

Try this, the width is `0dp` and using `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight` you can adjust the width as per your requirement.

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/iconIv"
   android:layout_width="36dp"
   android:layout_height="36dp"
   android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/nameTv"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameTv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some text"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iconIv"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/priceFl"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/priceFl"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nameTv"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

I prefer using `constraintStart` and `constraintEnd` instead of `constraintLeft` and `constraintRight`, just a personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp" //change here the distance between text and icon
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/iconIv"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/priceFl"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a fixed length "layout_width" rather than "wrap_content" this will solve your problem.However I recommend you to align the TextView to left and right of the images and price respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (also add paddings or margins according your design)

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/nameTv"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/iconIv"
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/priceFl"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```